# Getting ids from related models from the model of an object being created

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, model, relationship

I am very new to .Net and am having a bit of trouble I cant seem to find an answer to (likely because I am trying to do it incorrectly.

I am building a web application that will build and schedule tournaments created by users and I have the following 2 models:

```
 public class Tournament
{
    public Tournament()
    {
        Matches = new List<Match>();
    }

    public int TournamentId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser Owner { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Match> Matches { get; set; }
    public int PlayerCount { get; set; }
    public string TournamentType { get; set; }

    ...
    // More code here
}

public class Match
{
    public Match(int game1, int game2)
    {
        ...
    }

    public int MatchId { get; set; }
    public string Player1 { get; set; }
    public string Player2 { get; set; }
    public bool Completed { get; set; }
    public int PriorMatch1 { get; set; }
    public int PriorMatch2 { get; set; }
    public virtual Tournament Tournament { get; set; }
}
```

In the create action of the Tournament I am making a call to a method in the tournament Model called createElimination() which runs an algorithm for creating all of the rounds and matches that need to be played based off of the PlayerCount set for the tournament (I wont bore you with the huge [probably poorly written] algorithm).

The issue I am having is matches after the first round need to be created and store the ID's of the previous round's matches that lead into that match.

What I would like to do is as I am creating matches, store the ids for use in following rounds

```
foreach (Match match in currentRound)
{
    Matches.Add(match);
    lastRoundIds.Add(Matches.Last().MatchId);
}
```

but these matches are not added in the database until the db.SaveChanges(); is called in the controller so the id's are non-existent at the time of creation.

I am not sure how to solve this issue. Perhaps I should not be using the model for this logic and I should move it somewhere else?  Any help would be great.

Comment: Maybe call SaveChanges after Matches.Add.  It will add an extra database call for every iteration but seems like a necessary evil here.  At least the ID's will populate in the entities.

Comment: I believe to do that I will have to declare an ApplicationDbContext in the model so I have access there? Will that work or do I have to maybe pass the Controller dbContext to the model?

Comment: So don't work with ID values but with matches, i.e. the objects themselves.